# Creating a PKCS #7 detached signature for Apple Wallet passes using PHP

Tags: php, ios, ssl, sign, pkcs#7

This is an entirely new concept to me, so I'm shooting in the dark.

> To create the signature file, make a PKCS #7 detached signature of the
>   manifest file, using the private key associated with your signing
>   certificate. Include the WWDR intermediate certificate as part of the
>   signature. You can download this certificate from Apple’s website.
>   Write the signature to the file signature at the top level of the pass
>   package. Include the date and time that the pass was signed using the
>   S/MIME signing-time attribute.

### My understanding:

> To create the signature file, make a PKCS #7 detached signature of the manifest file

I'll be using the [`openssl_pkcs7_sign`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php) function using the flag `PKCS7_DETACHED`.

> using the private key associated with your signing certificate.

I'll be using the location of my ssl `cert.pem` file as the `signcert` parameter and the location of the `cert.key` file as the `privkey` parameter.

> Include the WWDR intermediate certificate as part of the signature.

I'll include the path to the WWDR certificate in the `extracerts` parameter

> Include the date and time that the pass was signed using the S/MIME signing-time attribute.

I'll include a an array with a key `signing-time` and value something like `2015-05-03 10:40:00` for the `headers` parameter.

### My code:

```
private function createSignature($dir)
{
    $cert = '/etc/ssl/cert.pem';
    $key = '/etc/ssl/private/cert.key';
    $wwdr = '/location/of/apple/wwdr/cert.cer';
    $headers = [
        'signing-time' => (new DateTime())->format('o-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];

    return openssl_pkcs7_sign("$dir/manifest.json", "$dir/signature", $cert, $key, $headers, PKCS7_DETACHED, $wwdr);
}
```

### Other questions:

I've noticed in the examples of the documentation for the `openssl_pkcs7_sign` function that *some* locations of the files are prefixed with `file://`. Why is this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Generate a Pass Type ID at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/passTypeId
2. Create a certificate for that Pass Type ID at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create/
3. Download the certificate and put it in your keychain
4. Find the certificate in your keychain and export it as `Certificates.p12` with no password
5. Open terminal, run `openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out pass_cert.pem -passin pass:` to generate the certificate
6. In terminal, run `openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -nocerts -out pass_key.pem -passin pass: -passout pass:YourPassword` to generate the key
7. Download the WWDR Certificate from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and put it in your keychain
8. Export the WWDR Certificate from your keychain as `wwdr.pem`

The function to create the detached signature:

```
public function createSignature()
{
    $cert = "file://location/of/pass_cert.pem";
    $key = "file://location/of/pass_key.pem";
    $wwdr = "/location/of/wwdr.pem";

    openssl_pkcs7_sign("/location/of/manifest.json", "/location/of/signature",
        $cert, [$key, 'YourPassword'], [], PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED, $wwdr);

    // convert pem to der
    $signature = file_get_contents("/location/of/signature");
    $begin = 'filename="smime.p7s"';
    $end = '------';
    $signature = substr($signature, strpos($signature, $begin) + strlen($begin));
    $signature = substr($signature, 0, strpos($signature, $end));
    $signature = trim($signature);
    $signature = base64_decode($signature);

    file_put_contents("/location/of/signature", $signature);
}
```

References:

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1
- https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass/blob/master/PKPass.php

Comment: Is this still working for you? I'm able to create the .pkpass file but my iphone will not open it