# openssl_pkcs7_sign(): no certificates in file AppleWWDRCA.cer

Tags: php, ios, ssl, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I need to create a detached PKCS7 signature for use with Apple Wallet passes.

### The code

```
private function createSignature()
{
    $cert = '/etc/ssl/local.crt';
    $key = '/etc/ssl/local.key';
    $wwdr = '/var/www/app/storage/passes/AppleWWDRCA.cer';
    $headers = [
        'signing-time' => (new DateTime())->format('o-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];

    return openssl_pkcs7_sign("$this->dir/manifest.json", "$this->dir/signature",
        $cert, $key, $headers, PKCS7_DETACHED, $wwdr);
}
```

### The error

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(): no certificates in file, /var/www/app/storage/passes/AppleWWDRCA.cer
```

`AppleWWDRCA.cer` was downloaded from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/. The exact certificate I downloaded was `WWDR Certificate (Expiring 02/07/23)`. I have viewed the file and confirmed it isn't blank. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding the AppleWWDR.cer to my keychain and exporting it from the keychain as a `.pem` file.

Comment: Where and what did you then do with the `.pem` file?

Comment: @AlexAtwater I just used a reference to the new `.pem` file in the function above, I belive. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124072/2172602